# how to use md-dialog code as a service or factory in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mddialog

my question is i have used md-dialog in most of the pages in our project.so thats why i decided to move all that md-dialog code to service.
mine FACTORY, HTML,  code
inside this factory i used $mdDialog.show({ //some code });

```js
App.factory('demo.controller',function(){

});
```

```html
<md-dialog>
 //some code
  </md-dialog>
```

and i don't know what to pass from the controller but i want to pass two parameters from the controller. Example:(opr,ev) so how to setup all these things any one help me.if possible send me the code.:)

Comment: If you include a snippet make sure it's working. Yours fails with `Uncaught ReferenceError: App is not defined`. If you can't put all of your code in a snippet, consider creating a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: service should be created to do some processing and return results... the DOM interaction should be handled in the controller. This way your service can become a reusable piece of software; If you can add a minimal code with exact help you need, you'll get more help more quickly